# What were the main results of the BaBar Experiment?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, cp-violation

I have been trying to find a review of the [BaBar experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BaBar_experiment) results for quite some time now. Can anyone link a few papers which illustrate what has been achieved so far?

Comment: Filtering in INSPIRE-HEP reviews by BaBar might be a good place to start: https://inspirehep.net/literature?sort=mostrecent&size=25&page=1&doc_type=review&collaboration=BaBar

Answer (score 1):

Did you try searching document servers? from [the CERN one](https://cds.cern.ch/?ln=en)

> The BaBar physics book : physics at an asymmetric B factory / Quinn, Helen R (ed.) ; Harrison, P F (ed.)
> SLAC-R-504. - Stanford, CA : SLAC, 1998. - 1056 p.

You could find it in a library.

Also by googling "review of BaBar experiment"

> [Submitted on 29 Nov 2004 (v1), last revised 15 Dec 2004 (this version, v4)]
> Review of Recent BaBar Results

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0411086

This is the Slac website  https://www-public.slac.stanford.edu/babar/ . Last entries are almost ten years ago.